# Using the include controller in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a recorded test which includes 2 pages a login page and another.I have made login page in include controller and the other in simple controller. I would like to know that if I run the test for 2 users how much time will the login page be shown in the result tree listener. I would like to have my test result tree as one login and multiple requests to the other page.Is it possible?

Comment: You want 1 login per user or 1 login per all test?

Comment: 1 login per all test

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755833/is-once-only-controller-runs-more-than-once-in-jmeter

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the include controller.... that is intended to include/load _other_ jmx files into " a parent" when it is run. I am also not clear what the listener has to do with what you want to achieve?? It would help if you actually defined the flow you want. Or showed some of your jmx to help understand what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: If I have 5 users I want only one login to be done and other page should be executed 5 times. I tried with two different thread groups but as there are cookies been passed it didn't work for me.

Comment: It seems you are asking different [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860969/sharing-cookies-between-thread-groups) for the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

*Note: the include question doesn't seem related to the actual problem*

Assuming you want 1 login *per* user and every logged in user executes 5 actions (samples), you would only need one thread group.

- Thread group (define appropriately for needed threads/loops)

  - [Config managers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) to set cookie/header/cache management
  - [CSV data set](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to define all user dependent values
  - login
  - action 1
  - action 2
  - action 3
  - action 4
  - action 5
  - logout

For very entry in your CSV these actions will be performed. The configuration of your CSV module will define what to do when the last user has been executed (e.g. stop or repeat).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute login only once you can add do the following:

1. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) instead of the Include Controller and use the following Condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy(ctx.getThreadNum() == 1 && vars.getIteration() == 1,)}
   ```
2. Put your "Login" request under the If Controller

This way "Login" request will be executed only during 1st loop and only by 1st virtual user.

Be aware that **other virtual users will not be logged in**. If you need to perform login once **per virtual user** consider using [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)